# Longtable column alignment problem

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, longtable, multicolumn

I have pages of table so I start to use `longtable`. My LaTeX input is given below. Even I use same code for each column, only first column is left aligned.

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}


\begin{center}  
\small  % Switch from 12pt to 11pt; otherwise, table won't fit  
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}           % default: \parindent  
\setlength\LTright{0pt}           % default: \fill  
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|l|l|l|l|l|l|}  
\caption[First Part Optimization Results]{First Part Optimization Results}  
 \label{grid_mlmmh} \\  

\hline \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Initial Points} \\ \hline     
\endfirsthead  

\multicolumn{6}{c}%  
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\  
\hline \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{Angle Thk} &  
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Angle Ht} &  
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Base Thk} &  
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Bracket Thk} &  
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Beam Thk} &  
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Maximum RF} \\ \hline   
\endhead  

\hline \multicolumn{6}{r}{Continued on next page} \\  
\endfoot  

\endlastfoot  

% \hline  
Angle Thk & Angle Ht & Base Thk & Bracket Thk & Beam Thk & Maximum RF             \\ \hline  
2 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 41212 \\ \hline  
2 & 9 & 6 & 1  & 8 & 51047 \\ \hline  
4 & 12 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 91721 \\ \hline  
7 & 14 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 135734 \\ \hline
```

Not exactly aligned right, but there is space at the remaining columns. Heading and numbers are not ordinate.

Thanks for help.

[image: The result is like this,]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Take a look at package `siunitx` for aligning numbers in a table. Also, package `booktabs` is worth a look to remove the number of lines.

Comment: How many times did you run LaTeX on that code? In general `longtable` needs more than one run to get alignment of columns right. Also, could you please make your code a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}` including all (but no more) packages needed to compile and reproduce your issue?

Comment: your image shows all columns left aligned. Also never put longtable in a `center` environment.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers can be aligned with package `siunitx`. Then the table heads are usually centered. Also, the following example uses package `booktabs` to show, how a table can be drawn with few horizontal lines only.

The example has stripped off the `longtable` stuff, because it is not needed to show the alignment with `siunitx`.

The table headers are formatted in two lines, because a comment said that the width of the table is a concern.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\cell}[1]{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=2.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=1.0]
  S[table-format=6.0]
}
\toprule
%\multicolumn{6}{c}{Initial Points} \\
%\midrule 
{\cell{Angle\\Thk}} &  
{\cell{Angle\\Ht}} &  
{\cell{Base\\Thk}} &  
{\cell{Bracket\\Thk}} &  
{\cell{Beam\\Thk}} &  
{\cell{Maximum\\RF}} \\
\midrule
2 & 10 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 41212 \\
2 & 9 & 6 & 1  & 8 & 51047 \\
4 & 12 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 91721 \\
7 & 14 & 3 & 2 & 6 & 135734 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]